# Rightmost tags in Favorite Tags are cut-off on the right

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, design, google-chrome

They're missing several pixels + the right border.

[image: Missing border]

Observed in

- Chrome 12.0.742.112 and 15.0.874.106 (on Windows 7)
- <strike>Firefox 5</strike>? (see comments)
- Opera (see [this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106541/rendering-bugs-with-tags-in-sidebar))

Comment: I don't believe this particular issue is actually reproducible in Firefox (I checked in various browsers). The answer below is referring to something else that looks kind of the same, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm fairly confident that this is a render bug in Chrome, which appears to be caused by the fact that the line wrap occurs at the end of an `inline` element that contains an `inline-block` element on its outermost edge.

It's also possible that this is a defined behaviour somewhere in the CSS3 specification since this issue only started appearing recently, but I haven't had time to check. It seems like rather undesirable behaviour though, so I'm still leaning towards bug.

That being said, it's fixable with a bit of a hack and without having to overhaul all of the CSS that's in play there. Since the edge is displayed so long as there's inline content at the end of the tag `<a>`, it's possible to just give it some:

```
#interestingTags .post-tag:after {
    content: '\200B';
}
```

Injecting a zero-width space counts for the purposes of rendering, but doesn't impact the expected display, nor does it interfere with the tag handling JavaScript.

Comment: This has been around forever; not new and always specific to webkit.

Comment: Hm, I'm only able to reproduce this specific issue in Chrome though, and it only started a few months ago (but I ignored it at the time, since I'm on Chrome dev). Safari doesn't exhibit this behaviour, at least not here.

Comment: I remember it being reported on superuser since forever, and SU has been around for over a year. You might be right about it being Chrome only, though.

Comment: Was just about to report this for Chrome 15.0.874.121 m

Answer (score 5):

I was hoping the Chrome team would fix this weird bug, but it doesn't look like they will. We have deployed the fix Tim Stone suggested. It will be in the next production build.

Comment: Yeah, I had poked around the WebKit source looking for what was causing this to submit a patch, but I wasn't able to narrow it down at the time. :/

Answer (score 3):

I can see a similar effect in FF5.

On SO, the last digit of the number of questions is incomplete: 1,822,31?

But I blame the browser, probably the zoom factor.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I created duplicate [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106541/rendering-bugs-with-tags-in-sidebar), but with the solution, so I'd move it there:

In Opera the tags on the second line and further don't have padding at the start, in Webkit there are no right padding and border on all lines except the last.

To fix it you can change the `display` of tags from `inline` to `inline-block` (and change some other style according to it).

There is a jsfiddle with the current and fixed variants: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/EaveS/

So, to fix it you must replace the following lines in the selector for the tags:

```
font-size: 90%;
line-height: 2.4;
```

to

```
display: inline-block;
font: 90%/1.2 Arial, sans-serif;
margin: .33em 2px .33em 0;
```