# Rendering bugs with tags in sidebar

Tags: bug, tags, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rightmost tags in Favorite Tags are cut-off on the right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98118/rightmost-tags-in-favorite-tags-are-cut-off-on-the-right)

Right now the tags in sidebar have `display: inline`, so when you add tags to favorite/ignored lists there are bugs in Safari, Chrome and Opera:

[image: Bug in Webkits]
[image: Bug in Opera]

In Opera the tags on the second line and further don't have padding at the start, in Webkit there are no right padding and border on all lines except the last.

To fix it you can change the `display` of tags from `inline` to `inline-block` (and change some other style according to it).

There is a jsfiddle with the current and fixed variants: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/EaveS/

So, to fix it you must replace the following lines in the selector for the tags:

```
font-size: 90%;
line-height: 2.4;
```

to

```
display: inline-block;
font: 90%/1.2 Arial, sans-serif;
margin: .33em 2px .33em 0;
```