# Why is the "how to move the turtle in logo" question closed?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wonder why this question is locked and closed:

[How do I move the turtle in LOGO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1003841/974555)

It's an actual programming question. Granted, it shows no effort of prior research, but usually that's not a reason for closing. How is this *not a real question*, and why is it *not considered a good, on-topic question for this site*?

Comment: "it shows no effort of prior research, but usually that's not a reason for closing"  Yes it is.

Comment: If you want it, background on the Turtle Question can be found by [searching Meta for "turtle"](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf8&oe=utf8&q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com+turtle). In particular, [Has a consensus been reached on whether or not some questions are too simple](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108006/) has a few useful links and explanations.

Answer (score 14):

This is the detritus of Stack Overflow changing its mind.

The question was originally asked by Joel to prove his point that *"No question is too simple"*, and we lived by that mantra for a couple of year.

Eventually, however, minds began to change: [maybe some questions *are* too simple](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/).

Nor is the questions *really* settled, [a "general reference" close reason has been firmly declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22general%20reference%22).

Comment: Simple is fine. No effort and research is not.

Answer (score 7):

See the gray bar below:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: FAQ.

Closed because it is not a real question.  And locked because it has some historical significance as a reminder when Stack Overflow was young and playfull,

Besides, the question has a high fun factor. (Hint look at the person who posted the question first).

Comment: My question is *why* it is not a real question. Isn't it a very practical, answerable and possibly useful question?

Comment: @gerrit It's too broad.  Answers to it would essentially be tutorials for the language.  Books have literally been written on the subject, which is a guideline for when a question is so broad that it should be "not a real question" on Stack Overflow.