# Questions accepted before now rejected

Tags: discussion

I have noticed something and i am quite confused about. There were questions that were asked about two years ago and got upvotes but if such type of questions are asked now, they get lots of down votes. For Example, i say a question that was asked two years ago. The question was

```
    What is the syntax for a for-loop in SQL?
```

This question got 10 upvotes but the day someone recently asked

```
    What is the syntax for SELECT statement in SQL?
```

The question got about 10 downvotes.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Over time, communities can change. In particular, they can decide that some types of questions are not a good fit, or not welcome.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192123/should-stack-overflow-be-a-last-resort-resource and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191248/did-so-used-to-have-fundamentally-different-rules-about-what-constituted-a-good amongst others.

Comment: Such old (now considered) low quality questions are closed as they are found. Had you linked them they would probably be closed by now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The community standards and the enforcement of the standards have changed over time. Whereas Joel once introduced "[How to move the turtle in LOGO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158289/why-is-the-how-to-move-the-turtle-in-logo-question-closed)" as a good question, easily researched/trivial questions are [now generally considered poor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Moreover, a lot of them are duplicates of earlier questions, so they are now often closed as duplicates.