# What is the best Stack Exchange site to use for beginner/intermediate programming questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

It seemed like I could go to Stack Overflow, but I'm fairly sure anything ending with "Overflow" was meant for professionals or at least people in the high end of that field, and didn't want to be downvoted to oblivion.

Is there another better suited Stack Exchange out there?

Comment: Stack Overflow is the only place for such questions at this moment.

Comment: That's somewhat disheartening :(

Comment: It would help to search for your question first, in case it has already been asked.  This may be the case for many beginner questions.

Comment: Maybe an old [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21871/158100) but this stll holds and more [recent with some good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215720/158100). I found those by using [this search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=are%20beginner%20questions%20off-topic)

Comment: [Are beginners' questions welcome (on Stack Overflow)?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271177/3524344) as well as the duplicate and other related questions in the comments.