# Minor css issues with ignored tags

Tags: bug, design, ignored-tags

Please check the tags pointed with red arrow. Tags pointed with green arrow are perfect. There is some issues with padding. Please take a look on tags pointed with Red arrow.

System:

Mountain lion, Chrome 21.0.1180.82

[image]

Comment: Can you please point out what is the problem exactly? Know that for some it's obvious from first glance in the screenshot, but for some it's not.

Comment: Also, bug is a bug no matter how minor. Please tag properly.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I have updated the question. There is some issues with padding. Please take a look on tags pointed with Red arrow.

Comment: hrm, thought this was fixed  [Rightmost tags in Favorite Tags are cut-off on the right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98118)

Answer (score 3):

As [Sathya mentioned in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145137/minor-css-issues-with-ignored-tags#comment414235_145137), there's already a fix in for this issue, but it seems to only be applied to the "Favorite Tags" portion (as you noticed).

I'm not sure if I made a mistake when I suggested the fix  previously or if that module's ID has since changed, but the problem should go away either way if the CSS declaration for `#interestingTags .post-tag:after` is changed to `#interesting-tags .post-tag:after`.