# Elements on right side are cut-off

Tags: bug, design

I have noticed that some elements on the right side of the Stackoverflow interface are cut-off. I have found a similar question ["Rightmost tags in Favorite Tags are cut-off on the right"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98118/rightmost-tags-in-favorite-tags-are-cut-off-on-the-right) on meta, but it is marked as completed. So i open a new one.

I have opened Stackoverflow in 3 diffrent browsers (Chrome, FireFox, IE 9) and all return diffrent results, but all cut-off elements on the right side. I have surrounded the areas with a red border.

**Chrome (23.0.1271.97):** Cut-Off Ignored Tags

[image: Cut-Off Ignored Tags]

**FireFox (17.0.1 / 18.0):**  Cut-Off Add Button

Increasing the Zoom Level to more than 100% displays the Button correctly. Lower than 100 %  i get diffrent behaviors

[image: Cut-Off Add Button]

**IE 9:** Cut-Off Single Tag

[image]

Comment: I've got the same problem at home, but I wasn't having the problem at work. I was figuring it was my huge monitor at home and the higher DPI settings I was using. I tried all levels of zoom and while it changed, it never got completely right.

Comment: I see it here, too. Chrome 23.0.1271.97

Comment: The first issue was reported here: [Minor css issues with ignored tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145137)

Comment: Do people _really_ favorite and ignore **that** many tags?!

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA yes i do. Maybe it needs some clean up

Comment: Protip: favoriting ".net-*" is a wild card and will auto-favorite all .net versions and tags matching that battern for you

Comment: @BenBrocka thanks for this great tip. didn´t know that feature.

Comment: This can be closed or tagged with a status tag, cause since the change on editing favorite and ignored tags, be problem vanished.