# Very small visual glitch in meta & stackoverflow

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Elements on right side are cut-off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161936/elements-on-right-side-are-cut-off)

I noticed the "Add" buttons in the right menu to add tags seem to be cut in Google Chrome Version 24.0.1312.56.

I also tested them in Iceweasel (Firefox) 3.5.16 (I know, I live in the previous millenium) and they seem to be properly displayed.

See the screenshot below for more information.

[image]

Comment: I get that on some browsers on some machines also, haven't pinned it down yet.  I was thinking it might have to do with video settings (like DPI) or zoom level.

Comment: I get that on Firefox 18, too.

Comment: Yeap, if you zoom the page to 110% in Chrome you see the full size button :)

Comment: I have this problem with one of the tags in my list. Only one though. http://i.stack.imgur.com/2kB0x.jpg

Comment: No repro here with exactly the same version. :S

Comment: Hmm, I'm in Debian Linux using mostly default settings (eg: font shape's 96 dots per inch, Smoothing set to Grayscale and Hinting set to Medium). Not sure if that has any effect on this.